# Maple and WolframAlpha return different results

Tags: maple, wolfram-alpha

I solved the integral of u/(1-u) by hand and found as result -ln(1-u) - u + constant. Now, when I evaluate this integral with WolframAlpha, I get the same result. But when I evaluate it with Maple, it gives me a different result. (This expression in the ln() is different). Does Maple do any strange conversions there, or did I do something wrong, or is it a bug in Maple? This is a screenshot to demonstrate what I did:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first thing that pops to mind: have you considered the domain of integration? If you integrate carefully, you should have absolute values within your logarithm, reflecting the difference arising if you want an antiderivative for $u > 1$ or $u < 1$. Maple gives you the one for $u > 1$.

Comment: Ok, I understand! Thank you :)

Comment: Or to put it another way, $\ln(1-u)$ and $\ln(u-1)$ differ by a (complex) constant...